# Return to last function when re logged due to session timeout (keep inputting data)

Tags: yii, session-variables, session-timeout

I want to return to the last function even if the session has timed out and have to logged in again. It would be nice if i can keep inputting data.

Ex: I am inputing data to a form and when I click submit, session has timed out. I have to relogin and I redirected to last form but I want keep all the inputed data in that form.

Give me some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use cookies.
You can store cookies after submitting form using yii cookies management or using javascript. And then load stored data to your form.

Here is article about yii and cookies

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/152/cookie-management-in-yii/
```

Hope this helps you.